# Copy last 4 digit of an existing column into a new column in mysql safely and without locking the table

Tags: mysql

I have a production table with millions of rows, I need to copy the last 4 digit of one col into a new col without locking the table, how can I do this safely?

Here is what I have, which failed git review:

```
    ALTER TABLE tokens ADD last4_token varchar(4);
    UPDATE tokens SET last4_token = SUBSTRING(full_token, -4);
```

Comment: Use a generated column instead of copying.

Comment: or if you actually need to be able to change last4_token to differ from full_token, use brute force: `update tokens set last4_token = substring(full_token,-4) where id between 1 and 100000; update tokens set last4_token = substring(full_token,4_ where id between 100001 and 200000;` ...

Comment: can you provide example of generated column in this case?

Comment: *I need to copy the last 4 digit of one col into a new col without locking the table, how can I do this safely?* For what purpose? a very dubious action..

Comment: "can you provide example of generated column in this case?" -> https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/alter-table-generated-columns.html ?

Answer (score 0):

There are two parts to that question:

1. How to add index without table lock

for that you can use pt-online-schema-change to do some magic to add field to the big tables without actually locking the table:
`pt-online-schema-change --alter "alter table tokens add last4_token varchar(4) default null, add index(last4_token);" D=db,t=tokens`
That will add field and index (index will be needed in the second point)

2. How to update that column with 4 last digits from other fields:

Run this query for number_of_records/100 times:
`UPDATE tokens SET last4_token = SUBSTRING(full_token, -4) where last4_token is null limit 100`

3. `pt-online-schema-change --alter "ALTER TABLE tokens DROP INDEX last4_token; ;" D=db,t=tokens` to delete index if needed

---

Another solution you can do without an index:

1. `pt-online-schema-change --alter "alter table tokens add last4_token varchar(4) default null"`
2. Generate update list:

```
Select concat('UPDATE tokens SET last4_token = SUBSTRING(full_token, -4) where id = ',id) from tokens into outfile '/tmp/sql.sql'
source /tmp/sql.sql
```

Comment: did you mean to have a limit 100 on the update?

Comment: @ysth yes, it will update 100 rows at the time

Comment: "Run this query for number_of_records/100 times:..."  doesn't have a limit

Comment: Ahhh you are right! forgot :) thanks